# How to get data in past 30 days in MYSQL and Print Past 30 days inside a loop using a variable in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get past 30 days sales records from MYSQL database to display in a bar chart how many items sold each day. Also I need to display past 30 days in my chart x axis in my php document. I tried run this code inside a for loop. because I am running some other codes to display some data using this loop. Take a look at the following code and help me how to achieve this.
This is the table I try to get data from

```
Date format (YYYY-MM-DD)

Products Table

product_id | sold_by | qty | added_date  | sold_date
-----------+---------+-----+-------------+-----------
3          | 12      | 7   | 2022-05-05  | 2022-07-28
3          | 12      | 7   | 2022-05-05  | 2022-07-29
3          | 12      | 7   | 2022-05-05  | 2022-07-30
3          | 12      | 1   | 2022-05-05  | 2022-07-30
3          | 12      | 2   | 2022-05-05  | 2022-07-30
6          | 22      | 4   | 2022-06-06  | 2022-07-31
8          | 11      | 6   | 2022-08-05  | 2022-07-31



Deleted Table

product_id | added_date  | delete_date
-----------+-------------+-----------
3          | 2022-05-05  | 2022-07-28
3          | 2022-05-05  | 2022-07-29
3          | 2022-05-05  | 2022-07-30
3          | 2022-05-05  | 2022-07-30
3          | 2022-05-05  | 2022-07-30
6          | 2022-06-06  | 2022-07-31
8          | 2022-08-05  | 2022-07-31
```

As you can see for some days I have multiple records.

```
<?php
//for loop to run 30 times to get 30 days results
for ($i = 30; $i >= 0; $i--) {
   $sold_products_count = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE sold_date = CURRENT_DATE - $i"));
   $deleted_count = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM deleted WHERE delete_date = CURRENT_DATE - $i"));
?> 
{
<?php
   $current_date = date("Y-m-d");
   $new_date = date_create($current_date);
   date_sub($new_date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("$i day"));
?>
   x: '<?php echo date_format($new_date, "Y-m-d"); ?>',
   a: <?php echo $deleted_count; ?>,
   s: <?php echo $sold_products_count; ?>,
},
<?php
}
?>
```

x- X axis data in the chart
a - number of products deleted in specific date
s - number of products sold in specific date

With the above code I was able to print the x axis data. I am not sure how to get past 30 days data from the SQL database. I think the problem is in the $i part in the SQL query.

Comment: You should never ever do `mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query`. This is terrible for performance and the wrong way of doing things. Learn to use `COUNT()` in SQL instead

Answer (score 0):

In your query, if you use `INTERVAL`, you can use some days for adding/reducing from the current or specific date.
For example in your case, if you always want to get the last 30 days data, you can use your WHERE like this:

```
sold_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Comment: If i am correct in this method i will get all the records in the past 30 days. But in here what i am trying to do is different. Lets say i need to get the data between 2022-07-01 to 2022-07-30. So when the code runs in the first circle of the loop i need to get how many items sold in the 2022-07-01. and in the second circle how many sold in 2022-07-02 and so on. At last round i need to get how many sold in today. Is there any way i can get it done.

Comment: If you just want to get report about count of sales for each product in every day, you can use `GROUP BY` in your SQL on your "date" & "product" and get sum of the sales, by this way, your result is data that each day has a product with the number of its sales.

Comment: `SELECT sum(qty) as sales_count, product_id, sold_date FROM products WHERE sold_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY GROUP BY product_id, sold_date`